# Python: Reading a file and calculating sum and average

Tags: python, file, list, exception

The question is to read the file line by line and calculate and display the sum and average of all of the valid numbers in the file.

The text file is

```
contains text
79.3
56.15
67
6
text again 
57.86
6
37.863
text again 
456.675
```

That's all I have so far.

```
numbers = open('fileofnumbers.txt', 'r')

line = file_contents.readline()

numbers.close()

try:
    sum = line + line
    line = file_contents.readline()
    print "The sum of the numbers is", sum


except ValueError:
    print line
```

Comment: Do you have a sample input?

Answer (score 2):

Using `with` notation can make dealing with files a lot more intuitive.

For instance, changing the opening and closing to this:

```
summation = 0

# Within the with block you now have access to the source variable
with open('fileofnumbers.txt', 'r') as source:
    for line in source: #iterate through all the lines of the file 
        try:
            # Since files are read in as strings, you have to cast each line to a float
            summation += float(line)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Might get you started

If you want to be a little more clever, there's a convenient python function called `isdigit`, which checks if a string is all integer values, which can let you do very clever things like this:

```
is_number = lambda number: all(number.split('.').isdigit())
answer = [float(line) for line in open('fileofnumbers.txt') if is_number(line)]
```

Which then makes sum and average trivial:

```
print sum(answer) # Sum
print sum(answer)/len(answer) #Average
```

Comment: Don't use `sum`, you'll shadow the function

Comment: @jonrsharpe whoops, can't believe I missed that one. Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 0):

Let's try list comprehension with `try-except`. This might be an overkill but surely a good tool to keep in your pocket, first you write a function that will silence the errors as such in http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576872-exception-handling-in-a-single-line/.

Then you can use list comprehension by passing in `argv` like you do in Unix:

```
intxt = """contains text
29.3423
23.1544913425
4
36.5
text again 
79.5074638
3
76.451
text again 
84.52"""

with open('in.txt','w') as fout:
    fout.write(intxt)

def safecall(f, default=None, exception=Exception):
    '''Returns modified f. When the modified f is called and throws an
    exception, the default value is returned'''
    def _safecall(*args,**argv):
        try:
            return f(*args,**argv)
        except exception:
            return default
    return _safecall

with open('in.txt','r') as fin:
    numbers = [safecall(float, 0, exception=ValueError)(i) for i in fin] 
    print "sum:", sum(numbers)
    print "avg:", sum(numbers)/float(len(numbers))
```

[out]:

```
sum: 336.475255142
avg: 30.5886595584
```

Comment: What are you writing to?

Comment: i'm writing the input to show that it achieves the desired output ;)

Comment: Seems a little more like spoonfeeding, and a little less like helping to answer a question.

Comment: i learnt from examples, i believe people learn from good examples too =)

Comment: Appending to a list in a for loop is not setting a good example :/
Neither is reading a string into a file and then right back out of a file.

Comment: Doesn't mean you have to go appending to a list when you're doing it. There are a dozen other ways that don't involve the super inefficient list appending. For instance: my answer.

Comment: dont think you can do average with that though, because that's what the OP needed too =)

Comment: give me a min, i'll suggest an alternative solution then =)

Comment: You certainly can, with extremely little difficulty even. I just didn't want to put 100% of the code down since this is a learning experience.